# open_uri / Nokogiri redirection problems

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am using Nokogiri for scraping a webpage that works fine unless the page has a redirection loop.

So when I scraping this site: https://www.cardcomplete.com/besuchen-isie-uns-auf-facebook/

I get this error

```
/home/balint/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:224:in open_loop': redirection forbidden: https://www.cardcomplete.com/besuchen-isie-uns-auf-facebook/ -> http://www.facebook.com/cardcomplete (RuntimeError)
```

But when I try to scrape this site I get the same error but now it is redirected to the https version of the facebook page:

```
/home/balint/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop': redirection forbidden: http://www.facebook.com/cardcomplete -> https://www.facebook.com/cardcomplete (RuntimeError)
```

Of course, scraping the https version of the facebook page works.

I installed [this open_uri_redirections](https://github.com/open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections) gem that works for the facebook http->https redirection but not for the first link:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.cardcomplete.com/besuchen-isie-uns-auf-facebook/', :allow_redirections => :safe))
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I was blind. I should have used `:allow_redirections => :all` instead of `:allow_redirections => :safe`.

Comment: Nokogiri has no connection or influence on reading a page. It *ONLY* retrieves data from the IO that OpenURI, or whatever you're using to read a page or file, hands it. In other words, Nokogiri isn't the problem, it's how you're reading the file. Originally, a lot of libraries would allow redirections from HTTP <--> HTTPs but that was deemed a confusing behavior so allowing that was discouraged, which is why `:safe` is the default and we have to explicitly turn on `:all`.

Comment: To use this :allow_redirection => :all, add a path by installing this gem https://github.com/open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections